# Django ListView Class with Mutli Query_sets Based On URL Slug

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.6, I have a class based view for viewing a log. With that, I have 2 different query_sets...for sorting the oldest date and the most recent date. I will be adding a couple of more query sets later.

How would I go about placing a slug in the url and having the class based view ViewLog() take that slug and based on that use the appropriate query_set?

Also, it seems messy to have if-then statements based on the slugs, but the only other alternative would be have different urls calling separate classes for a particular query_set...which seems more messy.

```
    url(r'^log_view/(w+)$', ViewLog.as_view(),
        name = "log_view"),
```

models.py:

```
class LogMostRecent(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Log, self).get_queryset().order_by("date_stamp")

class LogLeastRecent(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Log, self).get_queryset().order_by("-date_stamp")

class Log(models.Model):
    IRC_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 512
    date_stamp = models.DateTimeField()
    irc_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee,
            related_name='irc_name_log')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=IRC_MESSAGE_LENGTH)

    objects = AddLogEntry()
    most_recent = LogMostRecent()
    least_recent = LogLeastRecent()
```

views.py:

```
class ViewLog(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "bot_data/log_view.html"
    model = Log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

The best way would be by choosing the queryset in ListView's [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) from the slug you are using, so you don't create a whole bunch of similar views specifying a queryset for each one.

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
url(r'^log/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', ViewLog.as_view(), name="log_name"),
```

views.py

```
class ViewLog(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "bot_data/log_view.html"
    #model = Log
    #context_object_name = 'log_index'

def get_queryset(self):
    self.log = get_object_or_404(Log, slug=self.args[0])
    return Log.objects.filter(your_slug_in_model=self.log)

#def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
```